# After using Selenium to load the whole page, my code stop scraping after the first 100 items?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, chromium, imdb

I am trying to get a list of all the movie/series on my personal IMDb watchlist. I am using selenium to click the load more button so everything shows up in the html code. However, when I try and scrape that data, only the first 100 movies show up.
Nothing past 'page3' shows up.

The image below shows the part of the html that connotes page 3:

[image: In this photo there shows the part of the html that connotes page 3]

After clicking the load button with selenium, all the movies are shown in the chrome pop up. However, only the first 100/138 are printed to my console.

Here is the URL: https://www.imdb.com/user/ur130279232/watchlist

This is my current code:

```
    URL = "https://www.imdb.com/user/ur130279232/watchlist"
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
    
    driver.get(URL)
 
while True:
    try:
        watchlist = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lister-list mode-detail']")
        watchlistHTML = watchlist.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        loadMoreButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='load-more']")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(watchlistHTML, 'html.parser')
        content = soup.find_all('h3', class_ ='lister-item-header')
        #pdb.set_trace()
        print('length: ',len(content))
        for elem in content:
            print(elem.find('a').contents[0])

        time.sleep(2)
        loadMoreButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Even though after clicking load more button, "lister-list mode-detail" includes everything up until Sound of Music?

Answer (score 0):

Rest of the data is returned by doing HTTP GET to (scroll down and hit Load more)

https://www.imdb.com/title/data?ids=tt0144117,tt0116996,tt0106179,tt0118589,tt11252090,tt13132030,tt6083778,tt0106611,tt0115685,tt1959563,tt8385148,tt0118971,tt0340855,tt8629748,tt13932270,tt11185940,tt5580390,tt4975722,tt2024544,tt1024648,tt1504320,tt1010048,tt0169547,tt0138097,tt0112573,tt0109830,tt0108052,tt0097239,tt0079417,tt0071562,tt0068646,tt0070735,tt0067116,tt0059742,tt0107207,tt0097937&tracking_tag=&pageId=ls089853956&pageType=list&subpageType=watchlist

Comment: thank you for answering- I am unsure what you mean though? I see that in this link all movies that are not included when I scape is there, but I don't know how to apply HTTP GET

Answer (score 0):

What @balderman mentioned works if you can access the HTTP GET.

The main thing is that there's a delayed loading of the titles and it doesn't load the later ones until the earlier ones are loaded. I don't know if they only load if you're in the right region, but a janky way to get around it is to programmatically scroll through the page and let it load.

Comment: I am scrolling and loading through the entire page though? Or at least I thought I was

Comment: You might need to scroll down using something like
`for i in range(6): driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * {} / 5)".format(i)); time.sleep(3) `

Comment: Do I add that to my code or would I have to replace what I am currently doing?

Comment: Okay, so I added to my code. And it does not seem to solve my issue.

Comment: How did you add it? When I added it, it seemed to work?

Comment: My bad, I messed with order. It works perfectly now- thank you!!